# How to make \begin{align} counter start over again?

Tags: math-mode, numbering

I did a first `\begin{align}` with equations in a document and I did a second one.
Yet I noticed that the counter didn't started over again.

For instance here is the second equation which should start form one again.

[image]

Here is a code I hope that reproduce the problem but from which the photo is from.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\neg\phi\rightarrow\Box\neg\phi,w_i \mbox{ contrapositive of }T\\
\neg\neg\phi\rightarrow\neg\Box\neg\phi,w_i \mbox{ negation of }1
\end{align}

blabla    

\begin{align}
&\neg(\Diamond\Diamond p\rightarrow\Box\Diamond p),w_i\mbox{ hypothesis}\\
&\Diamond\Diamond p,w_i\mbox{ from } R_{\neg}\mbox{ on }3\\
&\neg\Box\Diamond p,w_i\mbox{ from } R_{\neg}\mbox{ on }3\\
&\Diamond\neg\Diamond p,w_i\mbox{ from } R_{\neg\Box}\mbox{ on }5\\
&\Diamond\Box\neg p,w_i\mbox{ from } R_{\neg\Diamond}\mbox{ on }\\
&w_iRw_j\mbox{ from } R_{\Diamond}\mbox{ on }\\
&\Box\neg p,w_j\mbox{ from }R_{\Diamond}\mbox{ on }\\
&w_jRw_k\mbox{ from } R_{\Box}\mbox{ on }\\
&\neg p,w_k\mbox{ from } R_{\Box}\mbox{ on }\\
&w_iRw_j\mbox{ from } R_{\Diamond}\mbox{ on }4\\
&\Diamond p,w_j\mbox{ from }R_{\Diamond}\mbox{ on }4\\
&w_jRw_k\mbox{ from } R_{\Box}\mbox{ on }13\\
&p,w_k\mbox{ from }R_{\Diamond}\mbox{ on }13
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure, that's understandable. If you want the counter associated with `align` (which is `equation`) to start with something different, you'll have to (re)set it: `\setcounter{equation}{0}`...

Comment: This is confusing readers, if multiple equations with the some numbers occur!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counters typically have a global scope, unless stated otherwise. In this case, `align` uses the `equation` counter, which you can (re)set as needed:

```
\begin{align}
  <your first alignment>
\end{align}

<some textual content>%
\setcounter{equation}{0}% Restart equation counter
\begin{align}
  <your second alignment>
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend this at all because it is confusing readers and potential hyperlinks will lead to the wrong place:

Place `\setcounter{equation}{0}` into `\align` with `\g@addto@macro`. Please note that this will have an influence on `\align*` as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\align}{\setcounter{equation}{0}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\neg\phi\rightarrow\Box\neg\phi,w_i \mbox{ contrapositive of }T\\
\neg\neg\phi\rightarrow\neg\Box\neg\phi,w_i \mbox{ negation of }1
\end{align}

blabla    

\begin{align}
&\neg(\Diamond\Diamond p\rightarrow\Box\Diamond p),w_i\mbox{ hypothesis}\\
&\Diamond\Diamond p,w_i\mbox{ from } R_{\neg}\mbox{ on }3\\
&\neg\Box\Diamond p,w_i\mbox{ from } R_{\neg}\mbox{ on }3\\
&\Diamond\neg\Diamond p,w_i\mbox{ from } R_{\neg\Box}\mbox{ on }5\\
&\Diamond\Box\neg p,w_i\mbox{ from } R_{\neg\Diamond}\mbox{ on }\\
&w_iRw_j\mbox{ from } R_{\Diamond}\mbox{ on }\\
&\Box\neg p,w_j\mbox{ from }R_{\Diamond}\mbox{ on }\\
&w_jRw_k\mbox{ from } R_{\Box}\mbox{ on }\\
&\neg p,w_k\mbox{ from } R_{\Box}\mbox{ on }\\
&w_iRw_j\mbox{ from } R_{\Diamond}\mbox{ on }4\\
&\Diamond p,w_j\mbox{ from }R_{\Diamond}\mbox{ on }4\\
&w_jRw_k\mbox{ from } R_{\Box}\mbox{ on }13\\
&p,w_k\mbox{ from }R_{\Diamond}\mbox{ on }13
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: **No comments** on the math typesetting please -- that's another issue